# Python script Send Packet to IP like packetsender.com

Tags: python, packet

i have trouble with python script to send packet. I already use socket.send like this :

```py
import socket
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(10)
    s.connect(("10.10.0.250", 8010))

    print(s)

    while True:
        try:
            s.send(b'1b02fa031b03c8')
            reply = s.recv(131072)
            if not reply:
                break
            print("recvd: ", reply)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("bye")
            break
    s.close()
except socket.error as socketerror:
    s.close()
    print("Error: ", socketerror)
```

**but show error : Time out.**
[image]
I have make sure that 10.10.0.250 is connected to my laptop.

send string i already try at application call [packetsender](https://packetsender.com/), use this tools all workwell.

[image]

**The question is WHAT SCRIPT PYTHON Equivalent with use in packetsender?**

Thanks anyway.
Regards

Comment: Is `10.10.0.250` on your local network?

Comment: yes, i already ping and get replay

Comment: does it print the socket?  (print(s) line)

Comment: Try running the script with `sudo`.

Comment: @EmmetB : 
```
<socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.100.39', 43410), raddr=('10.10.0.250', 8010)>
```

Comment: yes, i have try with SUDO but still error timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answer about this :

- Thanks alot to @jackw1111, your comment as clue : 
  When working with raw sockets in scripts, most operating system require advanced privileges (e.g. root user) to run them.
- Send packet must in ascii :

```py
packet = b'\x1b\x02\xfa\x03\x1b\x03\xc8'
s.send(packet)
```

- This article is helpfull https://inc0x0.com/tcp-ip-packets-introduction/tcp-ip-packets-3-manually-create-and-send-raw-tcp-ip-packets/

Thanks all